# Exporting .eps in Sketch leaves white boxes behind graphics

Tags: export, sketch-app, eps

Sometimes when I try to export ie a logo from Sketch, it leaves white boxes behind text etc.

It doesn't matter if I use outlined text or not, and they're not shapes either. I checked all my layers and there are no boxes in there. If I export it and open it back in Sketch, the white boxes are there as well.

How do I get rid of these annoying things?

- I added a screenshot of my layers. The bike is from a downloaded .eps, funnily enough that's the only thing not getting the white boxes. The rest is all made in sketch.

[image]

[image]

Comment: that's weird. Could there be some raster elements in there? Clipping masks? Did you create your elements in sketch or imported from another app? can you post a screenshot of what your sketch layers look like?

Comment: @spiral Added the screenshot and extra details, thanks!

Comment: It's hard to know without seeing your file, but it seems that only the elements with orange shadows are being somehow... rasterized? If you remove the shadows, does that fix it? Can it be some setting in the shadow?

Comment: @spiral deleting the shades indeed fixes it. Weird, it just has a 3px y shadow in a full orange color. No gradients, effects or whatever.

Comment: not a solution per se, but you can just reproduce the shadows with a copy of the elements behind

Comment: EPS has this by default like JPG. Like PNG is used for transparent background instead of JPG you can use TIFF instead of EPS.